# Change the value of selection box Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Option 1 is selected automatically from HTML which is equal to 10.

This is the HTML:

```
<form>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name:</th>
        <td><input id="search_term" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Page size:</th>
        <td>
            <select id="page_size">
                <option>4</option>
                <option selected>10</option>
                <option>20</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" id="search" value="Search" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

I tried running:

```
js = "document.getElementById('page_size').options[1].text ='1000';"
# js = "document.getElementById('page_size').options[1].text ='1000'"
driver.execute(js)
```

I get `KeyError` when i execute `js`. So I tried doing it the Python way, however, nothing happens:

```
x = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="page_size"]/option[2]')
x.clear()
x.send_keys(1000)
```

this is link i am testing on [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iytKt.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iytKt.png):[image: description from book on how to do it]'http://example.webscraping.com/places/default/search'

Comment: What are you trying to do? 1000 is not even a valid `option` in the `select`.

Comment: @RyanWilson i want to modify the option "text"

Comment: Huh? The point of automation is not to edit the page, it is to interact with it. If you aren't writing test automation, then changing the text of a button or OPTION or whatever isn't necessarily going to actually do anything other than visually change the page with no functional difference... if you are lucky. If you do manage to edit the page in some unexpected way, it's possible the site won't know what to do with the information and will either throw an error or otherwise not work.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to change the option elements text, I just tested this piece of javascript using jsfiddle and it works, try using "innerText" instead of "text":

```
document.getElementById('page_size').options[1].innerText = "1000";
```

Link to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z1omaue3/

Comment: `KeyError: 'document.getElementById("page_size").options[1].innerText = "1000";'`i had to change the single ' ' to " " so i am able to run it

Comment: @AmjasdMasdhash Then you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Ryan,I added the link in question if you can test there to check